# Searching/filtering design

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, search, entity-framework-5

I have an asp.net mvc4 application to (for purposes of this question) manage work requests. The main area of this application is just a list of all the work requests in the system, simple enough.

The requirements dictate that I need to build a fairly flexible searching/filtering system for this central list.

For example, the user needs to be able to search on fields like:

- Company
- Date created/completed
- user assigned
- various numeric fields (think product ids)
- priority
- status

Does anyone have any experience with designing a search like this for mvc4? I'm not quite sure how I should architect it. I thought of having one controller method that accepts a filter string (I'd like to use GET rather than POST so that the filtered list is linkable), but I'm not sure how I should parse that into something to send to my model, unless I send the actual filter string and somehow convert it into an expression (I'm using EF5 as well).

I'd also thought of creating a ViewModel specifically for searching but once again I'm not sure exactly how to set that up.

I apologize if the question is vague - I'm looking for some sort of guide or generic overview as to how I could build something like this. (I did do some searching but had no luck). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a model to hold the params like SearchParams, and then create a ViewModel for display results. The best exemple for search with MVC4, in my opinion, was made by the Own Asp.Net MVC team from Microsoft in the project Music Store. They take advantage from ajax to do that. Take a look here [MVC Music Store](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/releases/view/64379)

Hope this help you!

Comment: I took a look at that link, but I didn't see much about searching. Regardless, I'll try the viewmodel idea....

Comment: Well, they give an good exemple! That's a good way to start :)!! I did the viewModel idea, with ajax (get) to render the partial strongly typed view (using my ViewModel)!